# SQL Syntax Error, not my query

Tags: sql, syntax-error

I was given some SQL to run against our db and it is throwing a syntax error.  I have looked through and cannot find the missing expression.  Can anyone please assist?  It says line 6 column 42, which correlates to the first "ts".

Thanks,
Andrew

```
SELECT "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CNAME", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CHKEY3", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NENTEREDACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NINTERNTOEXTERNCALLS", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NANSWEREDACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."TANSWEREDACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."TTALKACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CHKEY4", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."DINTERVALSTART", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NHOLDACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."THOLDACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NABANDONEDACD", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NABANDONACDSVCLVL1", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NABANDONACDSVCLVL2", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NABANDONACDSVCLVL3", "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."NABANDONACDSVCLVL4"
FROM "ADMIN"."IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS" "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"
WHERE "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CHKEY4"=N'*' AND "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CHKEY3"<>N'*' 
AND ("IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CNAME">=N'ATEAM' 
AND "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CNAME"<=N'STORES') 
AND ("IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."DINTERVALSTART">={ts '2016-08-17 00:00:00'} 
AND "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."DINTERVALSTART"<{ts '2016-08-17 23:59:59'})
ORDER BY "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CNAME";
```

Comment: Valid ANSI SQL syntax, excect `{ts ...}`.

Comment: Never seen curly brackets used like that before...

Comment: This looks wrong:  `WHERE "IWRKGRPQUEUESTATS"."CHKEY4"=N'*'`

Comment: @DanBracuk: no, that's a valid SQL "nvarchar" literal (I think that is even part of the SQL standard - but at least Postgres, Oracle and SQL Server support that)

Answer (score 1):

`{ts '2016-08-17 23:59:59'}` is an escape sequence for JDBC (and I think ODBC as well).

Those escape sequences are (have to be) converted by the client side (driver) to a proper syntax before the statement is sent to the server.

So whatever SQL client you are using it apparently doesn't support that (it's not using JDBC or ODBC)

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer if that helps.  Should I change the "ts" to "to_date" and format that way?

Comment: @AWooster: Hmm, that's strange SQL Developer uses JDBC but it indeed complains for some reason (but I stopped trying to understand Oracle's decisions regarding their feature implementations). You might want to ask in Oracle's SQL Developer forum why that valid JDBC expression is rejected by SQL Developer